# Why can't I load TensorFlow model using tf.loadFrozenModel in tensorflowjs

Tags: tensorflow.js

I first train the model in TensorFlow，and I saved the model using `tf.saved_model.simple_save`. I succeed in converting to the tensorflowjs，but I can't load using `tf.loadFrozenModel` in tensorflowjs.

I have already uploaded files in GitHub. 
Here is the project: https://github.com/yiifanLu/tensorflowjs-problem.  Can you help me to check what the problem is?

If I use the *web_model_less* folder, the browser can correctly output. But when I use the *web_model* folder, it's always in await state. The difference between these folders are the number of parameters. In *web_model_less* folder I only use 4 convolutional layers. In *web_model* folder I use 8 convolutional layers.

I don't know how to solve this problem!

Comment: What do you mean by await state ?

Comment: the await state means when I load model  in web_model_less directory, the console output is only '111' .

Answer (score 2):

I was able to load the model on my machine, but obviously the model in web_model directory is quite big (80MB), but loading it should be fine.

You have a small mistake on the test page, you should call console.timeEnd on the second call. Can you share your console output when model failed to be loaded?

```
async function fun(){
    console.log("111");
    console.time('Loading of model');   
    const model_less = await tf.loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
    console.log("222");
    console.timeEnd('Loading of model');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.Can you load successfully  in web_model directory ?              On my machine,when I load the model in web_model directory ,the console only output  '111',so I think it may be alway wait.

Comment: May be you can successfully load in web_model_less directory,can you check which directory you load? Thank u

Comment: And can you list your device equipment you use in detail?

Comment: yes, I did load the web_model directory. You should check your network tab to see if any weight file downloads get stalled. If you can just post the screen captures of console and network tabs.

Comment: Oh，i  can  successfully load it with webstorm. I  used the sublime before,so i dont know why sublime can't load it